# How to access db file from the release apk in .net maui using Android studio?

Tags: android, maui

I'm working on one .net maui app which works on offline mode. To perform some testing I want to access sqlite db file from the release apk without using

- android:debuggable="true"
- Rooted device or emulator

Because both causes security issues.

Currently when I'm trying to access package from Android studio it shows:
**run-as: package not debuggable**

Can we do this?

Comment: Your app will need to copy the db file to a public folder

Comment: How to do that, please can you share any reference?

Comment: use `File.Copy`